# No usable keyboard after upgrade to systemd-210

Tags: linux, keyboard, freeze, systemd

I'm using Arch Linux and I've just updated to systemd-210 since it added the support for the keyboard backlight sav/restore my Macbook Air needed.
After having done the update, though, my keyboard is inusable (I'm typing from a USB keyboard right now) and this is the dmesg (I had to put it to pastebin since it was too long!):

http://pastebin.com/tpsLb09v

What could it be? Should I report this (critical) bug to someone? Who? The Linux Kernel bugtracking system? The systemd one?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I did as Gh. suggested but the dmesg error is still there.
This is my pacman.log:

```
    [2014-03-05 22:11] [PACMAN] upgraded systemd (208-11 -> 210-2)
[2014-03-05 22:11] [PACMAN] upgraded libpulse (4.0-6 -> 5.0-1)
[2014-03-05 22:11] [PACMAN] upgraded chromium (33.0.1750.117-1 -> 33.0.1750.146-1)
[2014-03-05 22:11] [PACMAN] upgraded gcr (3.10.1-2 -> 3.10.1-3)
[2014-03-05 22:11] [PACMAN] upgraded gdk-pixbuf2 (2.30.5-1 -> 2.30.6-1)
[2014-03-05 22:11] [PACMAN] upgraded gnutls (3.2.11-1 -> 3.2.12.1-1)
[2014-03-05 22:11] [PACMAN] upgraded lib32-glibc (2.19-1 -> 2.19-3)
[2014-03-05 22:11] [PACMAN] upgraded libgphoto2 (2.5.3.1-1 -> 2.5.3.1-2)
[2014-03-05 22:11] [PACMAN] upgraded libtirpc (0.2.3-2 -> 0.2.4-1)
[2014-03-05 22:11] [PACMAN] upgraded man-pages (3.60-1 -> 3.61-1)
[2014-03-05 22:11] [PACMAN] upgraded ntfs-3g (2013.1.13-4 -> 2014.2.15-1)
[2014-03-05 22:11] [PACMAN] upgraded ppp (2.4.6-1 -> 2.4.6-2)
[2014-03-05 22:11] [PACMAN] upgraded pulseaudio (4.0-6 -> 5.0-1)
[2014-03-05 22:11] [PACMAN] upgraded python2-lxml (3.3.0-1 -> 3.3.1-1)
[2014-03-05 22:11] [PACMAN] upgraded raptor (2.0.12-1 -> 2.0.13-1)
[2014-03-05 22:11] [PACMAN] upgraded systemd-sysvcompat (208-11 -> 210-2)
[2014-03-05 22:11] [PACMAN] upgraded telepathy-mission-control (5.16.0-1 -> 5.16.1-1)
[2014-03-05 22:11] [PACMAN] upgraded webkitgtk (2.2.5-1 -> 2.2.5-2)
[2014-03-05 22:11] [PACMAN] upgraded yelp (3.10.1-2 -> 3.10.2-1)
```

What can cause this?

This is a new dmesg log:

http://pastebin.com/V7C5dYBw

EDIT2:

I reported the bug to the kernel bugtracking system. This is the report:

https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=71551

Answer (score 2):

Recently, Systemd 210 caused a different problem for me. It did a bunch of problems and I ended up booting from my pendrive and chrooting into the Arch installation on the Hard Disk and installing the old version of systemd to resolve the issue. I am currently using 208-2.

You could try installing the old version of systemd for the time being, so you could use your laptop normally. It should cached in /var/chache/pacman/pkg.

Good luck.

UPDATE:
To get the previous systemd back, you can do this as oot:

> pacman -U /var/cache/pacman/pkg/systemd-208-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz

but just in case you are willing to install another version of systemd, just replace 'systemd-208-2-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz' with the version you used previously...

to see all of the versions that are still cached on your machine, simply do:

> ls /var/cache/pacman/pkg/systemd-*

UPDATE 2: Using dmesg output as a reference, I take it that you upgraded (208-11) to (210-2). in that case, you should downgrade using:

> pacman -U /var/cache/pacman/pkg/systemd-208-11-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz

and just to be on the safe side downgrade systemd-sysvcompat as well:

> pacman -U /var/cache/pacman/pkg/systemd-sysvcompat-208-11-x86_64.pkg.tar.xz

If it reports any dependency issues, you might need to downgrade those as well

Comment: How can I revert to systemd-208?

Comment: Thanks! Could you check my edit?

Comment: Yes, I do see the log. Thanks. But it says upgraded to 210... So this seems like the old log entry that was recorded earlier when you upgraded. I do hope that the download will work fine for you.

Answer (score 1):

Did you have read the news on the homepage of Archlinux?

https://www.archlinux.org/news/linux-313-warning-ps2-keyboard-support-is-now-modular/

By the way, also the responsible kernel package prints out a message:
https://projects.archlinux.org/svntogit/packages.git/commit/trunk?h=packages/linux&id=3234afe2e74bad47464efeda8ddc2edded7ca204

As stated on the news, most people with an AT-Keyboard (e.g. ThinkPads) shouldn't suffer any problem. But *Apple* is special in many ways, maybe in this case also.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't do the trick. Check my edit, though.